# differences of three function ( takes a function as an argument

Tags: haskell

What is the difference(s) between them?

```
 (i)
 gen ::  (a -> a -> a ) -> a -> a 
 gen  f x   = f x

 (ii)
 gen ::  (a -> a ) -> a -> a 
 gen  f x   = f x

 (iii)
 gen ::  (a -> a -> a -> a ) -> a -> a 
 gen  f x   = f x
```

first one gives error : "cannot construct infinite ... "

second one is work

third one not work

Comment: What's the difference? Why, you've written out the difference right there: the type signatures!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to figure out the type of the first function:
Imagine `a` is `Int` and `f` is normal addition. The second argument would be an `Int`. If you call e.g. `gen (+) 3`, the result is a function equivalent to `(+3)`, which takes an `Int` and returns an `Int`. But your signature says that you just give back an `Int`.

So basically the compiler complains because it expects an `a`, and you give it an `a->a`, and there is no way to unify these types.

To fix it, you could either correct the signature, which would be `gen ::  (a -> a -> a ) -> a -> (a -> a)`, or to change the definition, e.g. `gen  f x   = f x x`

The second one is just a specialization of the identity function `id :: t -> t`.

The third one is similar to the first one.